# Do pods share the filesystems, similar to how they share same network namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have created a pod with two containers. I know that different containers in a pod share same network namespace (i.e.,same IP and port space) and can also share a storage volume between them via configmaps. My question is do the pods also share same filesystem. For instance, in my case I have one container 'C1' that generates a dynamic file every 10 min in /var/targets.yml and I want the the other container 'C2' to read this file and perform its own independent action.

Is there a way to do this, may be some workaround via configmaps? or do I have to access these file via networking since each container have their own IP(But this may not be a good idea when it comes to POD restarts). Any suggestions or references please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an [emptyDir](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir) for this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: generating-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: consuming-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /cache
      name: cache-volume
  volumes:
  - name: cache-volume
    emptyDir: {}
```

But be aware, that the data isn't persistent during container recreations.

Comment: That's right!..Thank you so much. It works!!. And to add further, what I understand from your answer is that- " Different containers in a pod do not share the filesystem but in order to access files of other containers, one of the method is as you suggested ". Please correct me, if I am wrong.